# Override output operator << inside class c++ to print std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

Let's say I have a class as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

class RootFinder {
    public:
        RootFinder() = default;
        ~RootFinder() = default;

        friend std::ostream&  operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& v) 
        { 
            os << "[";
            for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) { 
                os <<"( "<< v[i].real() << "," << v[i].imag() << "), "; 
            }
            os << "]\n";
            return os; 
        }

        inline std::vector<std::complex<double>> calculateEigenValuesOfMatrix(){
            std::vector<std::complex<double>> eigen_values;
            //  Do some operation
            std::cout<< eigen_values << std::endl;
            return eigen_values;
        };
    
    private:
        
};

int main (){
    RootFinder root_finder;
    root_finder.calculateEigenValuesOfMatrix();
    return 0;
}
```

**Question:**
I want to print `eigen_values` inside the class itself.

I was trying to override the std::ostream&, but  it does not solve the problem. What is the proper way to solve this?

**Error:**

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::vector<std::complex<double> >’)
             std::cout<< eigen_values << std::endl;
             ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/istream:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/sstream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/complex:45,
                 from /usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/Core:80,
                 from /root/tmp/cmake_tittorials/include/root_finder.h:4,
                 from /root/tmp/cmake_tittorials/src/main.cpp:1:
```

Comment: What is wrong with code you have?

Comment: " it does not solve the problem" what does that mean exactly?

Comment: For this I would use a normal function instead of overloading the stream output operator. So just something like `output(std::cout, eigen_values)`

Comment: added the error message I get

Comment: As for the problems you have with the current code, please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. And copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build-log (as text) into your question. Add comments in the code where you get the errors.

Comment: please include a [mcve] in the question. The error message is from code you do not show currently

Comment: in the code you posted there is `// std::cout<< eigen_values << std::endl;` but thats only a comment. Details matter. Please post the code that produces the error not other code that needs to be modified to produce the error

Comment: There is no point to the overload you have being a friend. Define it before the class.

Comment: That error message comes with a line number. You've only given us a small part of the actual error, and I suspect it's being caused outside of the code you show us

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number it has only the minimum code, that can be used to reproduce the error, rest of the code I removed

Comment: The error you report is not from that code. Other users know nothing about your real code, they will take the code you posted copy it it somewhere, try to compile and *not* see the error you report.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/sK9ze8qvK

Comment: An ADL issue. Oh the joy...

Comment: A `friend` output stream operator overload is to output instances of the class itself, not of other unrelated classes and objects. Why did you make the `operator<<` a `friend` of `RootFinder`? It doesn't use anything in the `RootFinder` class, so can (and *should*) be a totally independent function.

Comment: On a side note, member functions defined inside the class definition are always `inline`.

Comment: it is also dangerous to overload `<<` for standard types. Suppose a library you use does the same. Issues will arise. A `RootFinder::print()` has none of those problems

Comment: On a couple of different notes: First don't end the output in your `operator<<` function with a newline. That's up to the user of the operator if there should be a newline at the end or not. Second, since this function have to be declared and defined as a normal operator overload, outside of the `RootFinder` class, it can be used by others to output `std::vector<std::complex<double>>` object, which might not be appropriate, or could collide with another similar overload. Hence my previous advice to create a normal function for your output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that even though you have defined the overloaded friend `operator<<` inside the class, it is **not visible through normal lookup** until either it is also declared in the enclosing scope or it has a parameter of the class type(so that ADL finds the friend function declaration).

##### Method  1

Here we provide a forward declaration for the friend function in the enclosing scope.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>

//add this declaration in the enclosing scope
std::ostream&  operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& v);

class RootFinder {
    //exact same code as before
        
};
int main (){
    RootFinder root_finder;
    root_finder.calculateEigenValuesOfMatrix();
    return 0;
}
```

[working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jM5qh5Ybd)

---

Other option is to define the friend function outside the class as shown [here](https://godbolt.org/z/WPfdT1TW9)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen *" I thought friend declaration puts a declaration in the enclosing scope "* The actual problem is that even though it "puts" the declaration in the enclosing scope, that **declaration is still not visible through normal lookup unless you provide a declaration outside the class as i did in my solution**

Comment: @Json yeap, this way I know :), I am just checking can we do it inside the class itself

Comment: @GPrathap Basically, we need to either provide an explicit declaration outside the class or the friend function should have a parameter of the class type so that ADL can be used. These are the 2 possible ways this can work.

Comment: @GPrathap its a free function. The only relation to the class is that is is a friend, but in your example there is no need to make it a friend. Maybe there is one in your real code, btu then still its a free function like other free functions.

Comment: @Json thank youu, I know those two methods, I was thinking there is another way, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to only print eigen values, better to create a standalone function (global free function or local private function) for printing the values:

```
class RootFinder
{
private:
    void print_eigen_values(const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& v) const
    {
        // TODO: add logic for printing to std::cout
    }
};
```

If you wish to print eigen values to any `std::ostream`, then you can create a function like:

```
class RootFinder
{
private:
    std::ostream& print_eigen_values(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<std::complex<double>>& v) const
    {
        // TODO: add logic for printing to os
        return os;
    }
};
```

then use it like: `print_eigen_values(std::cout, eigen_values) << std::endl;`.

If you want to retain eigen values for future operations, better to keep them as member of `RootFinder` and then you can overload `std::ostream` like below:

```
class RootFinder
{
private:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const RootFinder& v) const
    {
        // TODO: add logic for printing v.m_eigen_values to os
        return os;
    }

    std::vector<std::complex<double>> m_eigen_values;
};
```

which you can use anywhere like:

```
RootFinder r;
...
std::cout << r << std::endl;
```